# pymongo : How to replace many documents with list of dict

Tags: python, mongodb, replace, insert, pymongo

I am new with pymongo and I don't understand how I can run the equivalent from mysql to pymongo of

```
"REPLACE INTO XXXX (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5) VALUES" + results
```

I simply want to send to collection.replace_many() a list but it's not working.
I run

```
collection.replace_many(<list of dict>)
```

I got this error :

```
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'replace_many' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

I am using : pymongo.version : '3.11.2'

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB doesn't have a `ReplaceMany`; the equivalent to `REPLACE INTO` is `UpdateMany` (`update_many()` in pymongo) with Upsert set to True

Comment: okay thanks but i can't send list of dict in update many with pymongo ?

Comment: On the web i saw just a solution to update each document by for loop but is it possible to update many document from one request ?